# How can I get values from @GET using @QueryParam("list") final List<MyDTO> listDTO

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have an service that should receive a `List<Object>`, in my case, FaturamentoDTO... ex:

```
    @GET
    @Path(value="/teste")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<FaturamentoDTO> teste(@QueryParam("list") final List<FaturamentoDTO> listFatsDTO) {
        for (FaturamentoDTO f : listFatsDTO) {
            // do my stuff...
        }
        return listFatsDTO;
    }
```

So my question is, how can I send and receive the values.

JAX-RS specification says:

The following types are supported:

1 Primitive Types

2 Types that have a constructor that accepts a single String argument.

3 Types that have a static method named valueOf with a single String argument.

4 List, Set, or SortedSet where T satisfies 2 or 3 above.

But even with the constructor I can't get the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending anything other than simple strings I would recommend using a POST with an appropriate request body. However it must be possible with a GET.

How does your client send the request?
Your client should send a request corresponding to:

GET http://example.com/services/teste?list=item1&list=item2&list=item3

Comment: No problem using POST. Like I intend to use Android Asynchronous Http Client http://loopj.com/android-async-http/, my url should be: // url params: "users[][age]=30&users[][gender]=male&users[][age]=25&users[][gender]=female"

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters don't have any specific support for complex data structures, so you are going to need to implement that yourself.  I was facing something similar, and ended up using JSON representations of the data as the query parameter values.  For example (note that the JSON should be URL encoded, but I left that out to make it readable)

```
http://service?item={"foo" : "value1", "bar" : "value2"}&item={"foo" : "value3", "bar" : "value4"}
```

You could then write a [`ParamConverter<T>`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverter.html) to unmarshal the JSON into your FaturamentoDTO.  I am using JAXB/MOXy, but this could be done using your JSON handling library of choice.